# Accessing artifacts from previous run of the same build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I want to implement rerun solution for flaky tests.

[image]

I have problem with passing artifacts from previous run on build to next build.
`Artifacts B -> B (Run 2)`
Is there any option to get artifacts from latest run of the same build in same snapshot? For now I know that only option would be to get artifacts from Teamcity API.

Comment: no, Only API you able to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said before only option was to get latest build number from TC API and then get artifacts from API by this build number. There is no better option.

Get latest build:

```
https://teamcity.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=snapshotDependency:(from:(id:$parentBuildId),includeInitial:false),defaultFilter:false,buildType:$buildTypeId,state:finished,failedToStart:false,canceled:false,count:1
```

Get artifacts:

```
"https://teamcity.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:$latestBuildId/artifacts/content/$failed_tests_filename"
```

I'm answering in case if someone else will look for solution.